# MATLAB Index to Arrange Hourly Data by Months

Tags: matlab, indexing, leap-year

I need to create an index to help me arrange 25 years of hourly data (that is currently in date ascending format by hour from Jan 1, 1991 through Dec 31, 2015 in a 219144 * 54 array including leaps) into groups by month - including leap years.  The data record period is 1991 - 2015 so there are 6 leap years in that period.
The January data group would be something like 31*24 skipping the remaining hours of the year to the next starting place for the next year, etc. repeating 25 times.  Then the second column would be February accounting for leap years in a 28 or 29 * 24 with skips to each next year repeating 25 total times.  So, the final array will have 12 columns by X rows - but maybe there is a better solution.. I'm not sure how to account for the extra hours in the leap years.  Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read about [date and time object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html)? What does the 54 stands for?

Comment: 54 represents 54 different cases or sets of hourly data

Comment: What is the current shape of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is just a big  219144-by-54 matrix, you can use the following code to arrange the data in a big 5-D array, indexed by hour-day-month-year, and whenever there is no such date it has a `NaN`:

```
dstart = datetime(1991,1,1,0,0,0); % starting time is 01-Jan-1991 00:00:00
dend = datetime(2016,1,1,0,0,0); % End tine is 01-Jan-2016 00:00:00
entries = hours(dend-dstart); % the total number of hours
N = 54; % the number of samples in the data per hour

% some arbitrary data - this should be your data
data = repmat((1:entries).',1,N); 

Y = ceil(years(dend-dstart)); % the number of years in the data
M = months(dstart,dend); % the number of months in the data

% the output matrix that will contain all the rearranged data:
arranged_data = nan(24,31,12,25,N);

mstart = dstart; % starting month
counter = 1;
for mnth = 1:M % go over all months
    mend = dateshift(mstart,'end','month'); % get the month period
    dy = days(mend-mstart)+1; % find how many days are in this month
    yr = year(mstart)-year(dstart)+1; % find the relevant year
    [~,mo] = ymd(mstart); % get the number of the month (1-12)

    % extract the relevat part of the data:
    slice = reshape(data(counter:counter+dy*24-1,:),24,dy,N); 
    % and assign it to the correct place in the arranged array:
    arranged_data(:,1:dy,mo,yr,:) = slice;

    counter = counter+dy*24; % go to the next slice
    mstart = mend+1; % update the starting date
end
```

Now to extract a sample in some time you write:

```
arranged_data(hour,day,month,year,sample)
```

where `hour` is 1-24, `day` is 1-31, `month` is 1-12 and `year` is 1-25
`sample` is 1-54, and if you want all samples per time write:

```
arranged_data(hour,day,month,year,:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use matlab's datetime format providing it the year, month, day hours, minutes and seconds

```
somevariable=datetime(1991,1,1,00,00,00)
```

Add the indexes for whatever function you look at, if your data is hourly you can probably just concatenate the date variable onto your existing dataset.

```
alldates=datetime(1991,1,1,00,00,00):duration(1,0,0):datetime(2015,12,31,00,00,00)
```

Running the above code will generate a vector for every hour between 1991 and 2015.

If you haven't stored your data in a matlab table, consider using that as it will allow you to concatenate the disparate data types together. 
You can call a function like **array2table** which will convert your data into a table.

Once you have this formatted properly, you can easily group the data by using items like

```
month(somevariable)
year(somevariable)
day(somevariable)
```

To put it all together, you can run something like the code below, using logical indexing, to get all January data.

```
tablevariable=array2table(yourdata);
tablevariable=horzcat(array2table(alldates','VariableNames','Dates'),tablevariable)
tablevariable(month(tablevariable.Dates)==1,:) % this provides all data points for january
```